# External SVG fails to apply internal CSS

Tags: css, svg, external

I am trying to optimize one of my projects by using external SVG files to store anything that can save HTTP requests or bandwidth. My workflow usually consists of exporting all graphics to separate SVG files then combining them with `gulp-svgstore` after which its a fairly simple task to use them anywhere on the page.

However, until now I've always exported the SVG files with either inline CSS styles or by using presentation attributes. This time however I wanted to make use of the internal CSS option which stores all the styles at the top of the exported SVG file, inside of a `<style>` block. The reason is fairly simple, there are a lot of repeatable styles and reusing classes would maximize performance.

The problem is that all my attempts to load an external SVG file with internal CSS styles result in displaying black and white graphics, as if the internal styles are not applied.

Here is a Codepen demonstrating the problem.

**[DEMO](http://codepen.io/holodoc/pen/YGGRXB?editors=1000)**

There are three SVG files which were combined and pasted into the page, each representing one of the ways to export SVG from Illustrator:

- **Internal CSS** (puts all the styles in a `<style>` block)
- **Inline CSS** (adds all styles inline directly onto the elements)
- **Presentation atributes** - (makes use of SVG presentation attributes)

If the code is pasted directly into the page everything is displayed correctly (picture bellow).

[image]

However, if I move the whole SVG part (marked in the demo) to an external file both the inline CSS and the presentation attribute versions are displayed fine, but the internal CSS version is displayed as if none of the styles at the top are applied.

[image]

I've tried everything from adding appropriate namespace definitions like `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">` to experimenting with adding and removing certain parts of the external SVG. Nothing helps if the styles are part of the external SVG file which is loaded through `xlink:xref`.

I've really run out of ideas so any help is greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE**

The external SVG is loaded by simply giving a path to `xlink:href`.

```
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="path/to/the/file/file.svg#target"></use>
</svg>
```

As far as I know that has been a pretty standard way to include external SVGs for years. Of course IE lacks support for linking external SVGs through `xlink:href` but that issue is easily mitigated with [svg4everybody](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody).

I have temporarily switched to using inline styles on the exported SVGs which works as expected. However I would really like to know why loading external SVGs through `xlink:href` ignores all the internal styles from that very SVG file.

**UPDATE 2**

After a considerable amount of time spent on this issue I've simply come up with a conclusion that SVG parsers either completely ignore internal CSS styles contained within a `<style>` block of an SVG file which is loaded externally or there is a piece of the puzzle that I am still missing. Even pasting the `<style>` block within symbols, which are later reused with `<use>`, didn't help. Basically this simple use case does not work.

```
<!-- External SVG -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <symbol id="hello" viewBox="0 0 64 64">
        <style>.shiny{fill:#981e32}</style>
        <path class="shiny" ..."/>
    </symbol>
</svg>

<!-- Loading the symbol from HTML -->
<svg>
    <use xlink:href="path/to/external.svg#hello"></use>
</svg>
```

I am leaving this issue as is for now and switching to inline styles and presentation attributes because they seem to work flawlessly even with externally loaded SVG symbols.

Comment: @RobertLongson I've updated my question.

Comment: use clones the thing you link it to (the element with that id and its children) the style tag is outside that and does not get cloned or therefore applied.

Comment: @RobertLongson Unfortunately that didn't work. No matter what combination I used the external SVG file simply refused to use internal CSS. I've updated my question again but for now I am going to leave the issue as is and switch to using inline styles and presentation attributes. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Chrome 52.0.2743.116 m (64-bit) on Windows 7 here. Your codepen looks just like the first image in your post - i.e it displays all 3 logos just fine.

Comment: @enhzflep The first image just displays the correct behavior when all SVG code is part of the page. Codepen was just used to demonstrate that. The second image, however, displays what happens when the SVG code is moved to an external file and all three types of exports are loaded with `<use>`. Inline styles and property attributes work just fine. Internal CSS doesn't.

Comment: @holodoc - See, I just read the text "Here is a Codepen demonstrating the problem." and assumed it was what you said it was. Now, it seems you're saying the CodePen doesn't contain a problem. :ratherCounterproductiveAndConfusing:

Comment: @enhzflep Demo is just a common ground for *both* use cases which were extensively explained in the next couple of paragraphs. The first use case, where everything is in the Codepen, works fine. The second use case, where the first part marked with comment delimiters is moved to an external file, doesn't work. I am not sure how anything I've written could be interpreted as "counterproductive and confusing".